# Highlight label on input focus not working

Tags: html, css, sass

I have this in my HTML:

```
<label class="control-label" for="firstName">{{ 'OA_FIRST_NAME' | translate | uppercase }}<sup>*</sup></label>
<input
    formControlName="firstName"
    class="signup-input full-width" 
    type="text"
    name="firstName" 
    required>
```

And this in my SCSS:

```
input[name=firstName]:focus {

    background-color: blue !important;

    label[for=firstName] {
        background-color: red !important;
        color: green !important;
    }
}
```

the blue background for the input works but the label doesn't change at all.  Am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the `label` next to the `input` box and use `+` or `~` selector, i.e.

```css
input:focus + label {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<label>Label</label>
```

For visually reordering the input and label positions, see the simple demo with flexbox.

```css
.fieldset {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
.fieldset label {
  margin-right: 4px;
}
.fieldset input:focus + label {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="fieldset">
  <input type="text">
  <label>Label</label>
</div>
```

Comment: so is there no way of having this work with the label before the input?

Comment: @georgej You will need js for that I believe.